# How to increment counter in Gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I am new to gatling, I am trying to implement a counter. I am calling a post service by iterating through list of ids and I need to check the status for each iteration and increment the counter variable when the status is 200. I am have below code snippet,

```
def createData() = foreach("${userIdList}","userId"){
     exec(http("file upload").post("/compute-metaservice/datasets/${userId}/uploadFile")
       .formUpload("File","./src/test/resources/data/Test.csv")
       .header("content-type","multipart/form-data")
      .check(status is 200))   }
```

I need to add a if condition here something like **if(status is 200){counter++}**.  Can someone please help on how I can implement this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `session` to store the value and then in `exec` call check it and modify counter:

```
  var counter = 0
  def createData() =
    foreach("${userIdList}", "userId") {
      exec(
        http("file upload")
          .post("/compute-metaservice/datasets/${userId}/uploadFile")
          .formUpload("File", "./src/test/resources/data/Test.csv")
          .header("content-type", "multipart/form-data")
          .check(status.saveAs("uploadStatus"))
      ).exec(session => {
        if (session("uploadStatus").as[Int] == 200) counter += 1
        session
      })
    }
```

I'm not sure if this the best way, but it should work.

Comment: `counter` should be a session attribute instead of a variable. What you have is shared by all the virtual users in a non-thread-safe way.